# Problems using Python to SCP transfer files on Windows using os, Popen, and Paramiko

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko, scp

I am trying to get a Python script to SCP transfer a file to a SSH server to which I have root access and no password. I am on Windows and running;

```
scp test.txt root@<ip-address>:/data
```

works like a charm.

I have tried several different approaches to get Python to do this, but I run into trouble no matter what:

1. With `os`:

   ```
   import os
   my_scp = r'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe'
   os.system(my_scp + ' test.txt root@<ip-address>:/data')
   ```

   I get:

   > The specified path not found (translated so wording may be different)
2. With `Popen`:

   ```
   import subprocess
   p = subprocess.Popen(['scp', 'test.txt', 'root@<ip-address>:/data'])
   sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)`
   ```

   I get:

   > FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file was not found (again, translated)

   I have tried pointing to `OpenSSH\scp.exe` in a number of ways but to no avail.
3. With Paramiko:

   ```
   from paramiko import SSHClient
   from scp import SCPClient
   ssh = SSHClient()
   ssh.load_system_host_keys()
   ssh.connect('root@<ip-address>:data')
   with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as scp:
       scp.put('test.txt', 'test.txt')`
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File ".\my_script.py", line 6, in <module>
       ssh.connect('root@<ip-address>:data')
     File "C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 334, in connect
       to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
     File "C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 204, in _families_and_addresses
       hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM
     File "C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
   socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
   ```

I am running Python 3.7.3 in Windows 10.

---

Update - running `scp -v`:

```
PS C:\scp_test> scp -v test.txt root@169.254.108.26:/data
Executing: program ssh.exe host 169.254.108.26, user root, command scp -v -t /data
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: Connecting to 169.254.108.26 [169.254.108.26] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2017.75
debug1: no match: dropbear_2017.75
debug1: Authenticating to 169.254.108.26:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:RNaIuHs4U+5p8kQrcB+0pwCoKab3j6DNCk5hShNzpj4
debug1: Host '169.254.108.26' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\myself/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to 169.254.108.26 ([169.254.108.26]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /data
Sending file modes: C0666 5430 test.txt
Sink: C0666 5430 test.txt
test.txt
100% 5430     5.3KB/s   00:00
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 7080, received 1376 bytes, in -7.0 seconds
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Update II: I got it running by re-installing Python as 64-bit and using os to call OpenSSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Paramiko [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) incorrectly.

The first argument of `SSHClient.connect` is `hostname` (what can be also IP address as in your case). No username or anything else can be there. Username goes to `username` argument. The destination path (which has nothing to do with SSH connection) goes only to `SCPClient.put`.

This should work:

```
ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('<ip-address>', username='root')
with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as scp:
    scp.put('test.txt', '/data/test.txt')
```

---

Regarding your attempts to use `scp`: Just a wild guess, but I assume you use Win32-OpenSSH build of OpenSSH. It comes in 64-bit version only. If you use 32-bit Python, it cannot find 64-bit OpenSSH tools, like `scp`, because they are in 64-bit version of `C:\Windows\System32`. You can access it via magic name `C:\Windows\sysnative\OpenSSH\sftp`. Read about [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). Though you should not run a console application to implement SCP. Use native Python SCP implementation, like `SCPClient`.

Answer (score 0):

found solution if Win10 64 bit and Python 32 bit (3.8):

```
a = 'scp -r -i "path_to_your_key" path_to_file_want_to_send login@server_or_ip:path_on_server'
#  Also work if add ssh line to the a
# a += "\nssh -i path_to_your_key login@server_or_ip \"SOME COMMAND TO DO ON SERVER\""

filename = "sendjob.bat"
s = open(filename, "w+")
s.write(a)
s.close()
os.system('c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe /c c:\windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c start ' + filename)
```

My configuration:
Win10 office laptop without roots permission
and I needed sending files to the Linux server and then do something there.

Answer (score -1):

A possible issue with your first approach is you need to double up your backslashes. Backslashes are used in strings to denote special characters, but if you just want a backslash you want to have two of them

```py
import os
my_scp = r'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\scp.exe'
os.system(my_scp + ' test.txt root@<ip-address>:/data')
```

Comment: You do not need to escape backslashes in raw strings.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Thats my bad for not seeing that